# Best Java IDE for power consumption

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

I am a university student that has been working with java now for a few years. I have been using eclipse in that time, but I have started to take a look at intellij idea. One big thing that I am interested in is battery. At most times, I am using my macbookto program. The biggest issue I have with it is trying to get the most out of the battery as using a IDE + testing programs can use quite a bit of power. Does anyone know which IDE (IntelliJ IDEA / Eclipse) would be better on the battery, or do you know any tips that could improve the battery life using either IDE?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving battery life, and not about programming.

Comment: no battery = no programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question will result in opinionated answers+this not about programming. There are no **definite tests** on finding which uses less battery power.

As Daemon said the difference in power consumption is minimal/insignificant.

What you should be asking are the **objective differences** between either IDE. Many people have asked that on Stackoverflow, so you should look into that. The following link shows some objective differences between the two: [Differences between Eclipse and IDEA](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-idea-better-eclipse)

However, IDEA does come with a `Power Save Mode`; not sure if that's relevant to you? From the DOCS: [Power Save Mode](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/status-bar.html) *Select this check box to minimize power consumption of your computer on account of eliminating the background operations. When Power Save Mode is on, no inspections are performed.*

I suggest you carry around a battery charger.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I assumed that the question would still be relevant based on how many other discussions/"arguments" there were about different IDEs features and advantages/disadvantages

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) makes for a functional code editor without the extra features that add processing overhead (which is likely draining your battery somewhat, but not much).

In all seriousness however, you'll find that the difference between IDE's in terms of power consumption is minuscule, and can safely be ignored. If you want to see real improvement in battery life, consider switching to a less performance-hungry operating system, such as [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/).

If you're still concerned, consider stripping Eclipse or IntelliJ down to the bare minimum feature set required by your work.

Comment: I heard that Notepad uses even less power than Notepad++...

Comment: Of course, it's all that pesky syntax highlighting. Real programmers work in black and white.